# How to assess whether a non-designer values good design?

Tags: designers, client-relations, hiring

I am in a situation where I need to evaluate some people (non-designers) based on how much they value great visual design.

This is in the context of company branding, software product aesthetic & experience.

To be clear, my question is not about assessing someone's taste, or their innate ability to recognize good design, its about assessing whether they agree that its important to have good design.

For example, a CEO candidate might have absolutely no design skills and only layperson design knowledge, but their past actions demonstrate that they recognize the importance of design. Perhaps they have hired a Creative Director and empowered her/his team within the company. Perhaps they have repeatedly engaged with reputable design firms on major initiatives.

What questions can be asked? What observations can be made?

Comment: It's impossible for us to suggest questions or observations without knowing your exact purpose and desired outcome. As such I'm voting to close this question as unclear

Comment: Zach - I am evaluating potential co-founders for a software company. I want design to be an important part of the company's culture. My purpose is to evaluate individuals to know if they share these values.

Comment: So you want to partner with a non-designer (and you seem to also be a non-designer yourself) and want to know how to evaluate how they value the importance of design?

Comment: @go-junta Exactly, yes.

Comment: You could ask "how much do you appreciate good graphic and user experience design?"

Answer (score 1):

Here's two approaches you might be able to take something from:

**The direct**:

You're given a $100,000 budget that needs to be split between marketing and product development. How do you allocate the funds and where do you see those funds going within each sector?

**The less direct**:

*(find a few companies that you feel value design)*

Here are some successful companies. What features and differentials do you feel helps them stand out from their competition?

---

If they mention design at all in the budget or in what separates companies from their competition than you've got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking common people, ask common questions.

- What of these two do you like the most?
- Which one looks more ___________?
- Which one would you buy?